# How to send a silent push notification if the user disables them?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, push-notification

I'm working on a chat app and I need to know when a push notification is received to reload the conversation view with the new message. It's working well if the user allows the app to send push notifications to his device (with the notification dialog). However, if he taps "No" in this dialog, the following code, which registers the user device token to my database, is not executed :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    // Update the OneSignal id for this current installation
    oneSignal!.IdsAvailable({ (userId, pushToken) in
        if (userId != nil) {

            let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
            installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
            installation.setValue(userId, forKey: "oneSignalId")
            installation.saveInBackground()

        }
    })

}
```

Then, how to get the user device token, if he taps "No" in the notification dialog, so I can still target him to send silent push notifications ?

Thanks!

Comment: if user don't allow the push notification from the dialog then you are not able to send the push notification on his device unless user allows again from setting

Comment: As @pyro said, you're unable to receive notifications if the user has disabled them. You'll want to look into something like https://pusher.com/ or Pubsub for subscribing to notifications without polling.

Comment: @max_ But it will not work if the app is not in background. No idea how whatsapp does.

Comment: You can use application background modes to poll for changes

Comment: @max_ thanks for your suggestion! Didn't know about Pusher. It looks good. So the user doesn't have to allow push notifications if I use pusher ?

Comment: @fraxool no as it's all done through sockets rather than apns.

Comment: @fraxool Check out sinch.com. it works on sockets and you can implement one-one and group chatting with it. Easy to integrate and cheap as well.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible to do it but not with OneSignal.

Apple push notification does support push on the background, That means even if user doesn't grant access to notification it would just not show on his screen when he gets one.
With OneSignal the issue is that the system doesn't send a push to users who have disabled push notifications. That means that your notification won't ever reach your app because it won't ever be sent through Apple Push Service.

I suggest you use another vendor for that (it works with Parse-Server by the way).

If you want to fetch the data in background instead of using push I suggest you use "Background fetch", That would wake your app from time to time and let you run a bit of code to check if there is anything new.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration @Idan! Any suggested vendor over OneSignal?

Comment: @hyouuu I’m sure there is one that does it but I haven’t checked this out yet

Answer (score -1):

Sorry mate, you can't send apple push notifications to a device if the user doesn't allow Push Notification in settings, in that case you need to follow other methods to detect change in data.

1. You can implement sockets. i.e UDP connection which listens to the server for any incoming messages. You need to start the connection in the chat ViewController and and if you receive a packet indicating there is a chat message, you can reload data. Also there is live messaging service such as xmpp which is kind of the same but more improved with much more chat support. Chat services like Whatsapp uses them.
2. Another option is to reload data every 4 or 5 seconds using a `NSTimer` object. Call the api in background, so the user won't know it is constantly refreshing and update if there is new data. Also invalidate the timer once you go out of scope of the chat. The one i used, used the same technique with calling the api service both in chat view controller and conversation view controller.